# How do I align my TOC so the chapter names are on the right

Tags: ms-office

When I create an automatic TOC in my word document, the chapter names appear on the right and the page numbers on the left. I want it the other way around.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Apple hardware or software.

Comment: Check out help function in Word and this is not an Apple issue.

Comment: @Mark & SolarMike unless the OP is using Word for Mac (but he/she should indicate so; also, which version and a screenshot would be nice as well).